# Get utl parameters / URL rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to use URL rewriting to have "virtual" subdomains. I already created wildcard DNS entry.

I want subdomain to be added as GET parameter.

**Example:**

```
http://mysubdomain.domain.com/index.php
```

would call:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?subdomain=mysubdomain
```

and

```
http://mysubdomain.domain.com/page.php?parameter1=parameter
```

would call:

```
http://www.domain.com/page.php?parameter1=parameter&subdomain=mysubdomain
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)$ /$1 [L]
```

It works but I cannot get subdomain value, when calling other page than index.php, if I call http://subdomain.domain.com/page.php I loose subdomain parameter, I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)$ /$1&subdomain=%2 [L]
```

But I got Internal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%2 [L]
```

needs a `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%2 [L,QSA]
```

and this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)$ /$1 [L]
```

needs the `QSA` flag and the proper backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_.]+)$ /$1?subdomain=%2 [L,QSA]
```